# Hot Reload not working when React is externalized

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, webpack, ngreact

I'm attempting to integrate React components into our Angular 1.5.x application. I've been successful thus far in learning webpack and utilizing webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware; however, I'm running into a problem when using an external copy of React.

ngReact expects to find copies of React and ReactDOM. In addition, loading Angular and our controllers, directives, etc. takes precedence. To avoid loading multiple copies of React, I set the external property in `webpack.config.js`.

Now that React is externalized, it doesn't appear Hot Reloading works anymore. The terminal updates, HMR is connected according to the browser console, but the component on screen is not reloading.

Is there a workaround?